# How get the names of all the tables from a database in a combo box using c#

Tags: c#

Im using c# .net windows form application. i have a SQL database with 5 tables. i need to populate a combobox with these table names. only names should be displayed.

Comment: Which SQL database are you using?

Comment: 5 tables? comboBox1.Items.Add("table1"); ? you could have been done already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx#_FAQ31).

```
SELECT name FROM sys.tables;
```

Works for SQL Server 2005 and above.

Answer (score 1):

Can't know for sure until you specify what you're using, but this is a more or less standard query for retrieving the table names (excluding views) in the current database:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```