# List of all tables in database

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I get list of all tables in SQL Server database using query. My intention is to dynamically display this on a webpage.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT [name] from sys.tables
```

This should give you what you want. You'll then need to call it from your webpage to display in required format.

You may want to see:

- [How get the names of all the tables from a database in a combo box using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2636351/277290)

Will probably help you in what you are trying to do.

Also - you may want to see [SQL Server: should I use information_schema tables over sys tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653637/277290) for sys.tables vs INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

INFORMATION_SCHEMA is SQL92 standard, but I personally prefer sys.tables in MS-SQL universe as it seems (to me atleast) well structured and have all relevant information, e.g. **index information is just not available in INFORMATION_SCHEMA**.

Answer (score 11):

A more generic way:

```
Select *
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
Where TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
```